# Nasm ReadConsoleInput

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, crash, nasm

I'm currently working on a simple I/O console application compiled from nasm, but even though it compiles and links, it crashes when I run it. Here's the code:

```
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   equ -11
STD_INPUT_HANDLE    equ -10
NULL                equ 0

global start
extern ExitProcess, GetStdHandle, WriteConsoleA, ReadConsoleInputA

section .data
msg                 db "Hello World!", 13, 10, 0
msg.len             equ $ - msg
consoleInHandle     dd 1

section .bss
buffer              resd 2
buffer2             resb 32

section .text
start:

push    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
call    GetStdHandle

push    NULL
push    buffer
push    msg.len
push    msg
push    eax
call    WriteConsoleA

read:

push STD_INPUT_HANDLE
call GetStdHandle
mov [consoleInHandle],eax
push NULL
push 1
push buffer2
push dword [consoleInHandle]
call ReadConsoleInputA

exit:

push    NULL
call    ExitProcess
```

Any clues? I'm running a 64 bit windows 10 machine by the way and I'm using Nasm for compilation and GoLink for linking

Comment: Is this a 64-bit program? If so, [you are not following the amd64 calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx). ([More information.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040114-00/?p=41053/))

Comment: I'm guessing although you are using 64-bit Windows your intention is to target 32-bit executables with this?

Comment: The *lpNumberOfEventsRead* parameter of [ReadConsoleInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961.aspx) is not optional. You have to pass a valid pointer.

Comment: I know self promotion is against the rules here, but if you want to see the 64-bit implementation of this [I have one on my muck-around GitHub account](https://github.com/simon-whitehead/assembly-fun/tree/master/windows-x64/4.read-input). It accounts for not only the 64-bit calling convention, but the Shadow Space requirement of 64-bit Windows, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are targeting 32-bit Windows executables. You call `ReadConsoleInputA`, although it may be simpler to call `ReadConsoleA` if you are just interested in the characters entered from the keyboard. The title for your question says `ReadConsole Input` (a space between the two that puzzled me). Your code was:

```
push STD_INPUT_HANDLE
call GetStdHandle
mov [consoleInHandle],eax
push NULL
push 1
push buffer2
push dword [consoleInHandle]
call ReadConsoleInputA
```

[ReadConsoleA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958(v=vs.85).aspx) is similar in nature but handles just keyboard data. The code could look like this:

```
push STD_INPUT_HANDLE
call GetStdHandle
mov [consoleInHandle],eax
push NULL
push buffer    ; Pointer to a DWORD for number of characters read to be returned
push 1
push buffer2
push dword [consoleInHandle]
call ReadConsoleA
```

Although `ReadConsoleInputA` reads character data from the console, it handles a multitude of other events (including mouse, menu, focus, and keyboard) that you have to properly process (or ignore).

I'm assuming it is being built with commands to generate 32-bit executables like this:

```
nasm -f win32 test.asm -o test.obj    
GoLink.exe  /console test.obj kernel32.dll
```

If you want to target 64-bit executables, then all of your code will have to change since the 64-bit calling convention passes many parameters in registers instead of on the stack.

Comment: While it's true, that [ReadConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958.aspx) takes 5 arguments, both your code as well as the question call [ReadConsoleInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961.aspx) taking 4 arguments.

Comment: Your code passes 5 arguments to an API that expects 4. Please read my first comment again, exercising due diligence.

Comment: @IInspectable The reason I didn't see it was because the code I posted was not actually the code I ran. I originally modified the routine to call ReadConsoleA and presented the code with the improper call to ReadConsoleInputA. I have reworked my answer suggesting the OP consider ReadConsoleA if they are just interested in keyboard keystrokes. The confusing part to the question was the title which actually had `ReadConsole Input` suggesting they wanted to call `ReadConsole`. Thanks for pointing the issue out.